# Creating Properties object in Java

Tags: java

If we create a Properties like:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("[%1]", "username");
properties.put("[%2]", "password");
```

then what is added as the key in the properties.

Comment: Looks like an exam question to me...

Comment: Steps to find out without bothering the good people on SO: 1) File->Open 2) copy-paste 3) File->Save 4) javac.

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) inherits **put method** from [java.util.HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), thus your key would be `"[%1]"` and `"[%2]"` in your case.

[HashTable.put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

```
public V put(K key,
    V value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
properties.put(<key>, <value>);
```

This is what you want to know.

`Properties` is subclass of `Hashtable`, it represents a persistent set of properties.

`Properties#put` method is inheritated from super class `HashTable`.

Answer (score 0):

A fancy syntax

```
Properties props = new Properties() {{
    put("Key1", "Val1");
    put("Key2", "Val2");
}};
```